# annotation configuration - how to say spring configuration class location

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, annotations

Spring doesn't see request mapping for my controller. I try to use annotation configuration without xml.

Project structure:

[image]

### Config.java

```
package com.dnn.web.config;
//imports
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.dnn.spring")   
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {    
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

### WebInitializer.java

```
 package com.dnn.web.config;    
  //imports    
    public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
                throws ServletException {

            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            ctx.register(Config.class);

            ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

            Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
            servlet.addMapping("/");
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);        
        }        
    }
```

### HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.dnn.spring.controller;
//imports
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello( @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,   Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

When I invoke this application I see following result:

[image]

> localhost:8080/dnn-project/hello

returns same result.

I really don't understand where I made mistake.

**P.S.**
source code of this example: [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_j-PQh1R2eby1oLVpQanNyblE/edit?usp=sharing)

I suppose that Spring doesn't see `Config` and `WebInitializer` classes but I don't understand why and how to fix it.

**P.S.**

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dnn.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>dnn-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dnn-project Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>dnn-project</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**P.S.3**

if send request to this url

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

then

```
 мар 22, 2014 1:44:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)

...
```

Comment: Why are you going to `localhost:8080/dnn-project` when your mapping is to `/hello`?

Comment: localhost:8080/dnn-project/hello  doesn't work with same error

Comment: What about just `localhost:8080/hello`?

Comment: @chrylis hmm....java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config

Comment: @chrylis in my pom.xml exist dependency for servlet-api.  What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually everything fine with your Spring configuration. There only part that is missing is JSTL dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Tomcat does not include JSTL so it has to be shipped with your application.

Comment: Can you explain differences between 1. put libs to tomcat  2. or write it in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to refresh the ApplicationContext (`ctx.refresh()`)? There are some prebuilt  initializer classes in Spring that you can extend (or look at the source code of).

Comment: what should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spring is not able to read the configuration class `Config.java` from the `onStartUp()` method.

Try to define configuration as below:

`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();`
`context.setConfigLocation("com.dnn.web.config
Config");`

Source: http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/spring-mvc-without-web-xml-using-webapplicationinitializer/

Hope thos helps you.

Shishir

Comment: How to know url of deployed application?

Answer (score 0):

How about to add:

```
servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
```

to your `WebInitializer`  ?